# OpenGL Water fountain simulation

Tags: c++, opengl, simulation

My task is to create a fountain simulation with water particles and water surface collision. To this point I have created water surface using one shader, and another shader to create fountain particles (fountain particles' shader is also using transform feedback mechanism).

My question is: how can I make/detect fountain particles and water surface collision? - I would like to know, how can I get/connect information from plane's shader/GL buffer and particle's shader/GL buffer to make a collision - I know water wave equation and methods for collision detection - I just don't know for what allows OpenGL's API.

Comment: This question does not belongs here at all. This site is about helping people with problems, not giving solutions to general question. http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Can you describe water surface mathematically? I assume a particle is just a small sphere?

Comment: Maybe I gave incorrect question. I would like to know how to get plane vertices from plane's shader and particles' vertices from GL buffers to make a collision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're describing doesn't match OpenGL's job description. OpenGL is a drawing API, its purpose is to draw nice pictures. Things like collision detection are completely outside the scope of OpenGL.

However you can use OpenGL to implement a image based algorithm to perform image based tests matching your problem. In your case I'd render the water surface from atop in a orthographic projection, then render each particle with depth testing enabled. Using *Occlusion Query* I'd test if the particle was still visible. For each frame I'd compare if the particle visibility changed: If it disappeard it went underwater and collided.

This method works, but frankly I'd say it's totally overengineered. Just test if the particle height above ground is larger than the mean water level; for small ripple waves this is accurate enough.

Comment: Yes, second method is much easier and I know that I can do it simply in the particles' shader, but it implicates my next question: how will I know (or how program will know) what are the coords (X and Z) of this particle which is under a certain height (water has different shader) - so that I can create ripple wave on the water's plane in the place where particle collides with water surface? Should I precompute it somehow on CPU?

Comment: @Shot: You should deal with that in the code that does the particle animation. Also just like the particles you'll have to send some geometry to OpenGL to render the water surface; most likely some quad, on which you apply the ripple shader. You test against this quad's geometry, or just the plane it spans. You know, taking a plane equation, putting the particle position into it and test the resulting number for being positive or negative.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is investigate the possibility of OpenCL interop with OpenGL. Look [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_0/sdk/website/OpenCL/website/samples.html#oclParticles) for an nVidia sample that shows particle collision simulation using OpenCL (rendering using OpenGL). OpenGL is very limited as a compute API and it is quite hard to do what you want without jumping through hoops (I imagine is it possible - just not very easy).